# What's the difference between Statsmodel's Poisson and GLM with Poisson family?

Tags: statsmodels

For Statsmodels (imported as sm), I do not know what the difference is between

sm.Poisson(Y,X)

vs

sm.GLM(Y,X,family=sm.families.Poisson())

Also, another oddity is that with the former I have to use fit_regularize but with the latter, if I try to fit_regularize, I will get None when I try to get a summary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike sm.Poisson, GLM supports many different kinds of regression families.

The two appear to be different implementations of the same thing, with different options. For example, `freq_weights` are only supported on GLM poisson.

The missing `summary()` on GLM with fit_regularize appears to be unimplemented or a bug.  If the summary is important sm.Poisson supports it, or GLM supports it with the slightly different `fit_regularized(refit=True)` option.